# Ensure service worker is updated when hosted on a CDN?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

In production, our static files are served via Akamai (but on our domain), including our service worker.

By default we're caching the service worker but it doesn't seem to always be getting updataed.

What is the right strategy here? Should we set the service worker not to be cached ever and take a hit for every call in the service worker to pull the new service worker each time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The service worker, if there's a new one, should be updated at least every 24 hours, even if you set 'max-age' to a value greater than 24 hours: https://github.com/slightlyoff/ServiceWorker/blob/master/explainer.md#updating-a-service-worker

The browser will check if there's an update on every page load, but will obey the cache. So you can use 'max-age' to decide how often you want the browser to check for updates.

Comment: Likely a safe strategy when you're getting started is to set the cache headers / TTL to 0 to ensure it's always getting updated frequently and then increase it over time as you become comfortable with the setup.